# React: Array and Immutability Helpers

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to add an array to a state that contains an array. I wish to add the data to the end of the array. My data looks like this:

```
getInitialState: function() {
return {name: [{program: "File Manager"},
           {program: "Add File"},
           {program: "Index"},
           {program: "File Editor"}],
    program: "Index",
    display: true};
},
```

and I wish to update the name variable to also contain something. For example add {program: "Text Editor"}

How could I go about doing this with this.setState()? Or, if not, is there another way to do this. I read about $push but couldn't really find any examples that helped me out. I wish to do this in componentDidMount:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new array and assign it to the state:

```js
var currentName = this.state.name;
var newName = currentName.concat([{program: "Text Editor"}]);
this.setState({name: newName});
```

(The first line isn't necessary, just included for clarity.)

You could also use the function version of `setState`:

```js
this.setState(function(state) {
  return { name: state.name.concat([{program: "Text Editor"}]) };
});
```

If you're in an environment that supports [ES2015 arrows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you can do this in a pretty concise way:

```js
this.setState(state => ({ name: state.name.concat([{program: "Text Editor"}]) });
```

Since `concat` already generates a new array, you don't need to use the [immutability helpers](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/update.html), but if you want to, it'd look like this:

```js
var newState = update(this.state, { // generate a new state object...
  name: { $push: [ "TextEditor" ] } // with the item pushed onto the `name` key
});
```

It's possible to mutate an existing property of `this.state` and then re-set it with `setState`, e.g.

```js
// warning: antipattern!
this.state.name.push("Text Editor");
this.setState({name: this.state.name});
```

but this is not considered a very good practice [(you should always avoid directly modifying `this.state`)](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate):

> **Notes:**
>
> NEVER mutate `this.state` directly, as calling `setState()` afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat `this.state` as if it were immutable.

Comment: Thanks, setting a new array is super easy to do. Cheers,

Answer (score -1):

You can read the `this.state.name` array, modifying it (by pushing to the array), then call `setState` again.